# Back button not resized after device rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios11, xcode9

After I change XCode 7 to XCode 9, back button at all viewcontrollers stop correctly resizing after device rotation.

Navigation bar when viewcontroller loaded:
[image: Load view]

Navigation bar after change orientation to landscape and back to portrait:
[image: Button and title at different levels]
Button and title at different levels and arrow smaller then at first picture

Comment: Have you added custom button to navigation bar?  Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @nikBhosale it's a system back button, I don't change it. I use autolayout for view's but not for navigation controller

Comment: Ideally ff it's a system back button then it shouldn't trouble you. Maybe you can check for view debug hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your viewController in the method

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
```

just add a line `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()`.