# Back button in NavigationBar move down after rotate back to portrait in iOS11

Tags: ios, swift3, ios11, xcode9

When I rotate the screen to Landscape and then rotate back to Portrait the back button drop down somehow like this.

[image]

the original is this.
[image]

not only the title of back button but also the image drop down.
I tried to set the frame by the back button's frame before rotation but it's not working.
I'm sure the custom image of the back button is irrelevant.

The wired thing is I open an new testing project to reproduce the situation but it work perfectly.
I checked every setting in Navigation Controller from storyboard

[image]

or setting in Navigation Bar

[image]

They are all the same with my original project.
What do I missing?

This drop down only occur in iOS11.

Could it be the bug of iOS11?

Please help. THX

p.s. I'm using Xcode9.2

Comment: So I'm getting this on 6s, 7, and 8, but not 6s plus, 7 plus, or 8 plus. I'm also not getting it on iPad Pro (12.9 inch - 2nd generation). On the 6s, 7, and 8, I only get it if I have a controller prior to the navigation controller. If I make the navigation controller the initial view controller, then it works fine on 6s, 7. and 8. Only in iOS 11 - has to be a bug

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I see the same thing happening in my app.

Comment: sadly no. seems like the bug in iOS 11

Comment: Why are you creating your own back button? Why not just use the one that `UINavigationController` creates by default?

Comment: it's the default one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that calling `setNeedsLayout()` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799672/back-button-not-resized-after-device-rotation)) works.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Comment: That would make the app layout in an infinite cycle, even when not needed. Also, you're not calling `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. He should use a vertical center constraint to keep the button centered.

Comment: The cycle will not occur because they are two different objects: after our `UIViewController` did layout its subviews, then the `UINavigationBar` will layout up until the next update cycle, according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622601-setneedslayout?language=occ). Also, the `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` I think is not required because according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews) > Each subview is responsible for adjusting its own layout.